# Ruby on Rails: getting associated values to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm trying to create some kind of activity feed, and I'm having trouble getting the values I need to.

I have a controller with this action

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @ideas = Idea.find(@user)
    @lists = List.find(@user)
    @li_array = (@lists + @ideas).sort{|a,b| -(a.created_at <=> b.created_at)}      
  end
```

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to put together an array of values from the users of both ideas and lists. But I figured out that I can't do what I'm doing now because it will only pass the current user's id to match an id for Idea/List, but what I need to do is find the user's id column and search through based on @user.

I need to get all values from the users, what is the best method?

**models**

user.rb

```
  has_many :lists
  has_many :ideas, :through => :lists
```

list.rb

```
  has_many :ideas
  belongs_to :user
```

idea.rb

```
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@ideas = @user.ideas
@lists = @user.lists
```

Comment: You're welcome. This is very basic stuff, so you may want to have a look at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to learn more about how [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) work in Rails.